# Generating timestamp for each month start/end for a specific year

Tags: python, python-2.7, date

So I want the start/stop timestamp of each month for a specific year, so I came up with this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# --*-- encoding: utf-8 --*--

import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def convert_datetime_to_timestamp(datetime_object):
    return int((datetime_object - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())

def get_timestamp_one_month_later(timestamp):
    start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(timestamp))
    return convert_datetime_to_timestamp(start + relativedelta(months=+1))

def get_wholeyear_months_start_end(year):
    january_1st = convert_datetime_to_timestamp(datetime.datetime.strptime("{}/01/01-00:00:01".format(year), '%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S'))

    whole_year_timestamps = [january_1st]
    old_timestamp = january_1st
    for _ in range(12):
        old_timestamp = get_timestamp_one_month_later(old_timestamp)
        whole_year_timestamps.append(old_timestamp)

    return whole_year_timestamps

print get_wholeyear_months_start_end(1996)
```

which generates this :

```
820454401 = 1/1/1996 à 1:00:01
823136401 = 1/2/1996 à 2:00:01
825645601 = 1/3/1996 à 3:00:01
...
852145201 = 1/1/1997 à 20:00:01
```

As you can see each time there is a 1h delay.
I can't figure out why (I'm guessing this has something to do with my locale but what exactly?).

I'm using python 2.7 on a windows 7 with a French locale.

Thanks.

Comment: Let me understand. You want the timestamp for the instant at which, for instance, January began in 1996?

Comment: What is the expected outcome exactly ?

Comment: 1996/01/01 - 00:00:01 (first january 1 seond)
1996/02/01 - 00:00:01 (first fevuary 1 second), and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> for mois in range(1,13):
...     d = datetime(1996, mois, 1, 0, 0, 1)
...     '%s = %s' % (int(d.timestamp()), d.strftime('%Y/%m/%d à %H:%M:%S'))
...     
'820472401 = 1996/01/01 à 00:00:01'
'823150801 = 1996/02/01 à 00:00:01'
'825656401 = 1996/03/01 à 00:00:01'
'828331201 = 1996/04/01 à 00:00:01'
'830923201 = 1996/05/01 à 00:00:01'
'833601601 = 1996/06/01 à 00:00:01'
'836193601 = 1996/07/01 à 00:00:01'
'838872001 = 1996/08/01 à 00:00:01'
'841550401 = 1996/09/01 à 00:00:01'
'844142401 = 1996/10/01 à 00:00:01'
'846820801 = 1996/11/01 à 00:00:01'
'849416401 = 1996/12/01 à 00:00:01'
```

Comment: yup, I had been playing with timestamp all day so I totally forgot about datetilme constructor :x

Comment: Sometimes life is like that!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just something like this?

```
for i in range(1,13):
    print (datetime.datetime(1996, i, 1) - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Oh gosh, why did I code something so complicated, indeed I could do that. :x